# Taking the Vector Gradient of a Function in $(r)$ where $r = |\mathbf{\vec{r}}|$

Tags: vector-analysis, vector-fields, potential-theory

I have tried looking for the answer to this online, but probably due to my personal lack of knowledge have been unable to ask the question effectively.

Essentially I would like to understand how to take the vector gradient of the following equation (the equation has been left un-simplified deliberately):

$$u(r_{ij}) = D_0\left[e^{-2\alpha(r_{ij}-r_0)} - 2e^{-\alpha(r_{ij}-r_0)} \right]$$

Where $r_{ij}$ represents distance and is a magnitude and $r_0$, $\alpha$, and $D_0$ are constants. The only problem is I'm not sure what form the vector gradient equation would take when the distance is given as $r_{ij}$. Has anyone seen something similar?

My naive attempt is below using $\nabla_{ij} = \frac{d}{dr_{ij}}$:

$$\boldsymbol\nabla u(r_{ij}) = D_0\left[-2\alpha e^{-2\alpha(r_{ij}-r_0)} + 2\alpha e^{-\alpha(r_{ij}-r_0)} \right]$$

But I assume as its vector quantity a $\vec{r_{ij}}$ must fall out somewhere, I'm just not sure where!

For those who are interested the equation itself is the definition of an atomic pair potential that gives an energy value based on the distance defined by $r_{ij}$. The distance is the magnitude of the cartesian vector joining two atoms and is defined:

$$r_{ij} = |\vec{r_i} - \vec{r_j}|$$

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates

Comment: Are there a collection of atoms positioned at $\mathbf{r}_i$ and the $r_{ij}$ are the distances between these, i.e. $r_{ij}=|\mathbf{r}_i - \mathbf{r}_j|$?

Comment: Yes you're correct @md2perpe, that's the way to think of them.

Comment: @Andrei no I don't think so, I think the r represents a vector in cartesian space. So $\mathbf{r_i} = <x, y, z>$

Comment: Could it just be that I need to times the whole thing by the direction vector?

Comment: With respect to what position variable do you want to calculate the gradient?

Comment: I would like to calculate it with respect to all of them I guess, if it's all tied up in $\mathbf{r}$. Is this not possible? Is it possible instead I would have to replace the $r_{ij}$ with it's representation in x, y, z?

Comment: @md2perpe Could you take a look at my maths in the answer below and let me know if you think it's reasonable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition below may not be appropriate, but defining $\mathbf{\vec{r}}$ as:

$$\mathbf{\vec{r}}_{ij} = x \mathbf{\hat{i}} + y \mathbf{\hat{j}} + z \mathbf{\hat{k}}$$

Where $\mathbf{\vec{r}}_{ij}$ defines the vector between atoms $i, j$, and the values $\mathbf{\hat{i}}, \mathbf{\hat{j}}, \mathbf{\hat{k}}$ are unit vectors.

Gives you:

$$r_{ij} = |\mathbf{\vec{r}}_{ij}| = \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} = \left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{1/2}$$

Then defining $\nabla$ as:

$$\nabla = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \mathbf{\hat{i}} + \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \mathbf{\hat{j}} + \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \mathbf{\hat{k}} $$

Gives you:

$$\nabla u(r_{ij}) = \frac{\partial u(r_{ij})}{\partial x} \mathbf{\hat{i}} + \frac{\partial u(r_{ij})}{\partial y} \mathbf{\hat{j}} + \frac{\partial u(r_{ij})}{\partial z} \mathbf{\hat{k}} $$

This allows you to use the chain rule for each partial derivative, so for each partial derivative we have a variant of what's shown below for the partial with respect to $x$:

$$\frac{\partial u(r_{ij})}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial r_{ij}}{\partial x}\frac{\partial u(r_{ij})}{\partial r_{ij}}$$

Letting $r_{ij} = r$ for notational simplicity we have:

$$\frac{\partial u(r)}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\frac{\partial u(r)}{\partial r}$$

The first part of the right hand side of the equation can be calculated for $x$ as:

$$\begin{eqnarray}\frac{\partial r}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial \left(x^2 + y^2 + z^2\right)^{1/2}}{\partial x} &=& \left(2x\right) \left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \left(x^2 + y^2 + z^2\right)^{-1/2} \\ \\
&=& \frac{x}{\left(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \right)^{1/2}}\end{eqnarray}$$

As $r = \left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{1/2}$ this simplifies to:

$$\frac{\partial r}{\partial x} = \frac{x}{r}$$

Similar equations for the partial with respect to $y$ and $z$ can be found. This leaves the second part of the right hand side equation:

$$u(r) = D_0\left[ e^{-2\alpha(r-r_0)} -2e^{-\alpha(r-r_0)}\right]$$

Where again we have let $r_{ij} = r$, taking the partial with respect to r we have:

$$\frac{\partial u(r)}{\partial r} = D_0\left[ \left(-2\alpha\right)e^{-2\alpha(r-r_0)} - (-2\alpha)e^{-\alpha(r-r_0)}\right]$$

As $\frac{\partial u(r)}{\partial r}$ will be the same for all partials with respect to $x, y, z$ it can be factored out of the final equation and we have:

$$\nabla u(r) = \frac{\partial u(r)}{\partial r}\left(\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\mathbf{\hat{i}} + \frac{\partial r}{\partial y}\mathbf{\hat{j}} + \frac{\partial r}{\partial z}\mathbf{\hat{k}}\right)$$

Subbing in the partials with respect to $x, y, z$ along with $\frac{\partial u(r)}{\partial r}$ you get:

$$\begin{eqnarray}\nabla u(r) &=& D_0\left[ \left(-2\alpha\right)e^{-2\alpha(r-r_0)} - (-2\alpha)e^{-\alpha(r-r_0)}\right]\left(\frac{x}{r}\mathbf{\hat{i}} + \frac{y}{r}\mathbf{\hat{j}} + \frac{z}{r}\mathbf{\hat{k}}\right) \\
\\
 &=& \frac{-\left(2 \alpha\right)D_0}{r} \left[ e^{-2\alpha(r-r_0)} - e^{-\alpha(r-r_0)}\right]\left(x\mathbf{\hat{i}} + y\mathbf{\hat{j}} + z\mathbf{\hat{k}}\right)\end{eqnarray}$$

As $\mathbf{\vec{r}}_{ij} = x \mathbf{\hat{i}} + y \mathbf{\hat{j}} + z \mathbf{\hat{k}}$ you have:

$$\nabla u(r) = \frac{-\left(2 \alpha\right)D_0}{r} \left[ e^{-2\alpha(r-r_0)} - e^{-\alpha(r-r_0)}\right]\mathbf{\vec{r}}$$

Which finally simplifies to:

$$\nabla u(r) = -\left(2 \alpha\right)D_0 \left[ e^{-2\alpha(r-r_0)} - e^{-\alpha(r-r_0)}\right]\mathbf{\hat{r}}$$

Where $\mathbf{\hat{r}} = \frac{\mathbf{\vec{r}}}{r}$ and is a unit vector in the direction of $\mathbf{\vec{r}}$, here the notation has also been simplified and $\mathbf{\vec{r}} = \mathbf{\vec{r}}_{ij}$ from the original definition.